# SQLite options not appears in Generate Database From Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I wanna to use SQLite with Entity Framework, and wanna to using the drag and drop Database Designer(It is very convenient :p), I am new to using Visual Studio 2019, and installed `System.Data.SQLite` and `Microsoft.Data.SQLite` related packages, But sqlite data source option is not appears in `Generate Database From Model`

[image]

Comment: Try to install SQLite Toolbox

Comment: @ErikEJ I installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox, but not work

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/wiki/EF6-workflow-with-SQLite-DDEX-provider